# R : Time serie for dygraphs

Tags: r, time, dygraphs

First, I am not a pro in R and I have difficulties to manage date and time series, I would appreciate any advices  like tutorials on this topic that I may find on the web.

I would like to plot a dygraph of a time serie here is my code

```
library(lubridate)
library(dygraphs)
library(zoo)
library(xts)

#the data
data1<-rnorm(105120)

##data between 2014-01-01 and 2014-12-31 every five minute
d1<-seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-12-31 23:59:00"), by=300)

#data frame
df <- data.frame(cbind(d1, data1))
```

Then

```
 #time serie
 ts1<-ts(df[,2], start=0,end=365*24,frequency=60/5)
```

I don't know How to define a time serie between two date??

some tests I try with help on the web

```
##test
z1 <- as.zoo(ts1)
z1xts <- xts(z1 , date_decimal(index(z1)))
```

Dygraphs tests but none of it works

```
##test dygraph 
dygraph(df) %>% dyRangeSelector()
dygraph(ts1) %>% dyRangeSelector()
dygraph(z1xts) %>% dyRangeSelector()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
dygraph( xts(x = data1, order.by = d1) ) %>%
  dyRangeSelector()
```

[image]

Please read `?xts`

Comment: Thanks a lot Faidherbard.

Appreciated.